# Is it possible to execute downloaded code on WP8?

Tags: mobile, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

**[Aside from the fact that this is a terrible idea]**

I know downloading and executing code on iOS is strictly forbidden (developer agreement ss 3.3.2), and that it is indeed possible on Android.

I can't find any mention of this for WP8.

I'm curious about either (or both) interpreted code/scripts like JavaScript, and compiled code as well.

Answer (score -1):

the OS is closed.so no way. at least I haven't heard about it.

with regard to JS - it's strictly possible, using webbrowser component and its **InvokeScript** method